# Ajax request seems to be called twice, however other javascript along with the Ajax request is only called once

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a code that uses ajax to get the contents of a PHP page every X seconds until `completed=="yes"`, and every time it gets the contents it echo's a `<script>alert("checked");</script>`, while in the php page I have it echo `<script>alert("worked");completed="yes";</script>`.

So, ideally, it would alert `checked` once, then it would also alert `worked` once. For some odd reason it's alerting `checked` once (as it should) but it's alerting `worked` twice.

My javascript code is...

```
<script>
var completed = 'no'; 
function checkit() { 
    if (completed == 'no') { 
        $('h1.countdown').load('website.com/check.php'); 
        setTimeout(checkit, 10000); // makes it reload every 10 sec 
        alert('checked'); 
    } 
} 
</script>
<h1 class="countdown"></h1>
```

While my PHP code is

```
 echo '<script>alert("worked");completed = "yes";</script>';
```

Does anyone have any idea why the PHP code would be ran twice?

Comment: My guess is the timeout's not cleared on success.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a race condition, try:

```
$('h1.countdown').load('website.com/check.php', function() {
    setTimeout(checkit, 10000); // makes it reload every 10 sec 
    alert('checked'); 
});
```

Also, you missed a closing quote after check.php.

Comment: I tried that and I get the same result, only this time it is alerting the "worked", then the "checked" then the "worked" again instead of "checked" first, then "worked" twice